# Какое окончание у существительного «жучок» в сочетании «оставили "жучок"»?

Tags: падежи, существительные

Правильно ли я выбираю окончание существительного в данном сочетании (см.заголовок), если в данном случае «жучок» — подслушивающее устройство?

Полиция оставила («жучок»?)
Спасибо заранее.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всё верно, одушевлённое существительное, употреблённое для обозначения неодушевлённого предмета, считается существительным неодушевлённого разряда и, следовательно, при склонении окончания В.п. и И.п. совпадают:

*Полиция оставила "жучок".*

Для указания на переносное значение обычно слово берут в кавычки.